# Select CheckBoxes in Listbox via user32.dll? (

Tags: c#, windows, user32

I have a Handle for a ListBox from an external application.

Now I have a Listbox with x Items which I want to select with the WinApi.

I tried this with SETCURSEL but its unfortunatly doesnt work:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr chldWnd = NativeMethods.FindWindow("#32770", "Ansichten einfügen");
    IntPtr ListBoxHandle = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(chldWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "ListBox", null);
    //MessageBox.Show(ButtonHandle.ToString());
    NativeMethods.SendMessageInt(ListBoxHandle, NativeMethods.CB_SETCURSEL, 1, 2);
}

static class NativeMethods
{
    public const int BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;
    public const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;
    public const int VK_DOWN = 0x28;
    public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    public const int LB_SETSEL = 0x0185;
    public const int CB_SETCURSEL = 0x014E;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="PostMessage" ,CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageInt(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wsg, IntPtr wParam, String lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the way I use it will meet your need to select an item with a mouse click on the ListBox, Please, try it.

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

 public void SetListItem(string windowTitle, int index, int item)
        {
            try
            {
                var windowHWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, windowTitle);
                var childWindows = GetChildWindows(windowHWnd);
                const int LB_SETCURSEL = 0x0186;
                const int downCode = 0x201;
                const int upCode = 0x202;
                IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)9999; // The coordinates
                IntPtr wParam = IntPtr.Zero;

                SendMessage(childWindows.ToArray()[index], LB_SETCURSEL, item, "0");

                SendMessage(childWindows.ToArray()[index], downCode, wParam, lParam); // Mouse button down
                SendMessage(childWindows.ToArray()[index], upCode, wParam, lParam);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```